# C memory allocation, what is wrong?

Tags: c, memory

**(Solved)** This line(in C)

```
(*ptr).firstNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
```

gives this error:

> [Error] incompatible types when assigning to type 'node' from type 'void *'

So, the left part is of type "node" (which is a structure that i created), why is this not working? Does anyone know? Any help would be appreciated, will post the structs declarations if necessary.

Structs:

```
typedef struct node{
    int idade;
    struct node * next;
    struct node * prev;
}node;
```

and

```
typedef struct {
    node firstNode;
    node lastNode;
}dll;
```

**Guys, the question is solved, thanks everyone that answered, would it be better to add firstNode and lastNode as pointers? or would it be better to just let them be the struct itself?**

What i'm trying here is just to learn how to initialize and deal with a double linked list, this is just the creation of the list itself, next functions will be remove from the top and from the bottom, etc.

Comment: Yes, it is necessary to post the `struct` definition. Though it looks like `firstNode` is not a pointer type

Comment: Indeed, it's of the type of the struct itself (not a pointer)
wlil edit with definitions

Comment: If it isn't a pointer then you can't (and don't need to) assign the result of `malloc` to it

Comment: Hmm yeah you're right, Is it already assigned on the creation of the dll struct?

Comment: It's "assigned" in the sense that it has automatic storage duration.

Comment: So, why are you trying to do this `(*ptr).firstNode = malloc(sizeof(node));`? What are you trying to achieve? Given your set of definitions, this just does not make any sense.

Comment: Yes it didn't, was just a mistake, was trying to create a "createList" function and put it there, but it wasn't needed, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

malloc returns a `void *`, as the error says..

> [Error] incompatible types when assigning to type 'node' from type
>   'void *'

you need a pointer on the left-hand side which should be of type `node*` in this case.

Maybe you should change the struct definition like this

```
typedef struct {
    node *firstNode; // pointer 
    node *lastNode;
}dll;
```

then `(*ptr).firstNode = (node *) malloc(sizeof(node));` would work.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
typedef struct {
    node *firstNode;
    node *lastNode;
}dll;
```

Since the others in the comments already noted, firstNode is not a pointer, but  a struct.